# Do harvest sprites take care of the dog and horse?

Tags: harvest-moon-back-to-nature

The harvest sprites are able to water crops, harvest crops, feed animals, brush animals, etc. Do they also care for my dog and horse? Do they brush the horse? Do they lift the dog?